# I want to simplify this regex, /^data$|^data-/,what should I do?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to match data or data-a or data-b or data-abcdefg.

```
 /^data$|^data-/
```

I feel like it could be simplified, but I'm not good at this。

Comment: Please define "simplify". Also, please specify what regex flavour. It is not clear what you intend by `$|^`. Are the `/` supposed to be matched or being used as delimiters?

Comment: I suggest `^data(?:$|-)`.

Comment: data or data-a or data-b or data-abcdefg.

Comment: What's possible also depends on which precise regex tool or dialect you are using; as already required in the [`regex` tag description](/tags/regex/info), please [edit] to provide these details.

Comment: For traditional ERE, `^data(-.*)?$` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify the current pattern to get the same matches as that you will get with you current pattern, you can make the hyphen optional. Note that this will give you a partial match.

```
^data-?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OxUgBy/1)

If you want to match the whole line, you can optionally match a group (in this example a non capture group if that is supported) that starts with a hyphen and then match the rest of the line:

```
^data(?:-.*)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0oNtY/1)